# Log-out on Computational Science

Tags: discussion

Is it possible to log out from this website? I am trying to find the log out button - but not very successfully.

Answer (score 6):

Welcome to SciComp! If you click on the StackExchange button in the upper left corner of the page, you should see under "Current Community" Computational Science, and to the right on the same line "log out". Click on the link, and you should be logged out.